Google Chrome keeps giving a Startup Error 0x12524 when Installer runs
Whenever I try to install Google Chrome, it gives me a startup error 0x12524. I've tried asking around and checking the internet, but nothing I've tried has worked so far.
I've currently tried:

Editing the Registry
Cleaning out the files
sfc /scannow
Drive Health Repair
Powershell
Repair Install

Does anyone have any advice on how I can fix this without having to resort to a full system reinstall?

Install how? Where and when does the error appear?

I’m trying to run the normal installer exe. When I do, it immediately gives the error.

Try uninstalling it with BCUninstaller. Although there might not be any success if you manually deleted files and modified registry.

Would REVO uninstaller work?

Tried it. Still giving me the error.

Revo is worse and less effective. Also, try different installers, e.g. from winget or Choco.
